# Getting the "Error: [$resource:badcfg] object]" when I call http get request

Tags: angularjs, http

I'm a new developer and I'm having some issues. I'm using AngularJS and I use a service to return the users from a database.

I have an factory in my Service.js to specify the http service:

```
dashboard.factory('User', ['$resource', 'urlPrefix',
    function ($resource, urlPrefix) {
        return $resource(urlPrefix + '/user/json/getUsersByName', {
            id: '@id'
        }, {
                getUsersByName: {
                    globalError: false,
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: true
                }
            });
    }
]);
```

The user controller receives two entries(userName and maxResults):

```
@ControllerSupport
public List< User > getUsersByName() {

    String userName = getParameter( "userName", String.class );
    Integer maxResults = getParameter( "maxResults", Integer.class );
    return userService.findByName( userName, maxResults );
}
```

I'm calling the service as you can see above:

```
$scope.queryDashboardUsers = function () {
        User.getUsersByName({
            'userName': $scope.username.search,
            'maxResults': 100
        }).$promise.then(
            function (response) {
                console.log('users', response);
            });
    };
```

And receiving the following error:

> Error: **[$resource:badcfg] ** object http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.20/$resource/badcfg?p0=array

As I was reading in the forum, query returns an array and get returns an object.

So I've tried to call:

```
return $resource(urlPrefix + '/user/json/getUsersByName', ...).query();
```

and

```
return $resource(urlPrefix + '/user/json/getUsersByName', ...).get();
```

And neither them worked.

If I look at "Network" in Chrome, I can see the request response and that's right. So I imagine that I'm having a problem of conversion between Object and Array but I have no idea where.

Could someone help me?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: I assume we're talking about AngularJS. Vitor, please update the title, the question and the labels and provide a little bit of context to your question, especially the language and framework used.

Comment: Yes, it's Angular JS. Thanks Philipp Jardas, I'll try to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem changing the service to:

```
dashboard.factory('User', ['$resource', 'urlPrefix',
   function ($resource, urlPrefix) {
        return $resource(urlPrefix + '/user/json/getUsersByName', {}, {});
    }
]);
```

But I really don't understand why the service before didn't work. Does someone know?